Allow the anonymous user access to the user.logout route
Ok, I've tested this against drupal/recommended-project:^8, ^9 and ^10. Nothing else installed.
I want anon users to be able to hit /user/logout. That's the requirement.
IMO, this code (or a close variation) should do the job:
<?php

namespace Drupal\modify_user_logout\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class ModifyUserLogoutRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
  {
    if ($route = $collection->get('user.logout')) {
      // $route->setRequirement('_access', 'TRUE');
      $route->setRequirements(['_user_is_logged_in', 'FALSE']);
    }
  }

}

But no, whatever I try (setRequirement(), setRequirements(), _access, _user_is_logged_in, removing requirements entirely), something is redirecting to <front> before the requirements check even fires.
What hope someone will say I'm using setRequirements() wrong, and to give me a working example, but I'm pretty sure I'm not. To me it looks like some other bit of core that's earlier in the bootstrap than the requirements check is checking whether or not the user is logged in for this route specifically, and throwing a redirect to <front> if they are not. That feels like a bug to me.
Any input gratefully received.
Edit:
As @Clive mentions below, an Exception is raised before we ever get to the requirements checks, and this bit of code from AccessDeniedSubscriber::onException() throws us out (note the hard-coded check against the $route_name):
elseif (in_array($route_name, ['user.logout', 'user.logout.confirm'], TRUE)) {
  $redirect_url = Url::fromRoute('<front>', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]);
}

The Exception in question is a CacheableAccessDeniedHttpException with the message 'csrf_token' URL query argument is missing.
This was thrown by AccessAwareRouter::checkAccess():
protected function checkAccess(Request $request) {
  // The cacheability (if any) of this request's access check result must be
  // applied to the response.
  $access_result = $this->accessManager->checkRequest($request, $this->account, TRUE);
  // Allow a master request to set the access result for a subrequest: if an
  // access result attribute is already set, don't overwrite it.
  if (!$request->attributes->has(AccessAwareRouterInterface::ACCESS_RESULT)) {
    $request->attributes->set(AccessAwareRouterInterface::ACCESS_RESULT, $access_result);
  }
  if (!$access_result->isAllowed()) {
    if ($access_result instanceof CacheableDependencyInterface && $request->isMethodCacheable()) {
      throw new CacheableAccessDeniedHttpException($access_result, $access_result instanceof AccessResultReasonInterface ? $access_result->getReason() : '');
[...]

So I need to figure out why $this->accessManager->checkRequest($request, $this->account, TRUE); returns an AccessResultForbidden on the user.logout route.
More to follow, hopefully.

Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This is a Q+A site, and as such it's important to ask a specific question - what question are you asking? If it's "is this a bug?", that's something to be addressed in the core issue queue (discussion about bugs doesn't happen here for hopefully obvious reasons). If you're looking for a workaround, it'd be good to edit the body and mention that specifically, just so it's clear what people are answering. Thanks!

Just incase as you didn't mention it. You've added the relevant code into your modify_user_logout.service.yml file?

Personally I'd say it's not a bug though, rather a feature which prevents a paradox. An un-authenticated user can't logout, so this is just preventing the impossible.

Have you stepped through with a debugger?

@unusedspoon yup, best to seek the obvious solution first, but yes, I just quoted the relevant bits of the module. For the avoidance of doubt:
services:
  modify_user_logout.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\modify_user_logout\Routing\ModifyUserLogoutRouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }


@Clive I knew somebody would say that :) There's a sane reason for this, I promise, I just my example down to the essentials.

@monalisa yes, to a point. I'll amend the question in an hour or so with my findings but the TL;DR is "something throws an Exception, and that Exception 301's the user to 

Yep, I drew the short straw ;) Another place user.logout redirects to the home  page is Drupal\user\EventSubscriber\AccessDeniedSubscriber::onException()). But that fires in response to an access denied exception, so it's either not the smoking gun for your case, or the access is in fact being checked, but the route modification isn't working. First step would probably be breaking in the user.logout part of the event subscriber to make sure that's definitely what's happening. Bear in mind that even if the access check passes, the user.logout route controller still redirects to home

@Clive yes, that's exactly what's happening - I'm getting an Access Denied exception that redirects to front. This is why I consider it a bug - or at least programmer error on my part - because my intention is for the user to load that route, so they shouldnt be getting AccessDenied.
My belief is that altering the requirements of the route should be sufficient to avoid the access denied exception, but obviously I'm missing something.

The commments of @Clive are correct.
It's no problem removing all access restrictions from the route. I've tested it and there is no longer an access denied exception thrown. Remove also the CFSR token restriction if the link doesn't have it in the query string.
However, the behavior doesn't change. Even if you pass the route access check and reach the controller there is a second redirect to the same destination:
UserController::logout()
  /**
   * Logs the current user out.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
   *   A redirection to home page.
   */
  public function logout() {
    if ($this->currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
      user_logout();
    }
    return $this->redirect('<front>');
  }

Working example for the route subscriber:
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Mymodule route subscriber.
 */
class MymoduleRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('user.logout')) {
      $route->setRequirements(['_access' => 'TRUE']);
    }
  }

}


as an experiment, could you do me a favour? Throw an exit("i am here"); at the top of the logout() method, and see if it ever fires? If it does, I'd be really grateful if you'd show me the code you're using.
The behaviour does change if you're also overriding the route controller in your alterRoutes() method. Like I said, I promise I have sane business requirements here. I'm not asking the wrong question, and this isn't something I need to work around. I need to find a way to have anonymous users load the user.logout route.

I've used Xdebug. After removing all route restrictions no more exceptions were thrown and the controller did run. Replace the last line in the controller return ['#markup' => 'This is UserController::logout!']; and you see this after clearing Drupal and browser caches.

Ok, by "removing all route restrictions" I assume you mean my code from the original question but with $route->setRequirements([]); in the if(). If I'm wrong, please correct me. I modified UserController::logout() as you suggested, but I'm still seeing a CacheableAccessDeniedHttpException raised before I reach that point. If you could dumb it down for me a bit by editing your original answer to show your working code, I'd be really grateful.

"Remove also the CFSR token restriction if the link doesn't have it in the query string." <------ I bet this is where I'm tripping up. How do you do this? (I'm looking at it now).

Thank you so much. Your comment about the CSRF token was what put me on the right path. I ended up calling $route->setRequirements([]); to wipe the token and $route->setRequirement('_access', 'TRUE'); so I didn't get a Neutral response, but obviously your example code above does the same thing more neatly. I'm left wondering why I didn't try that exact combination before I posted - and why the logout route needs a CSRF token at all. Something to investigate. Thanks again.
